# How to easily publish web site from VS2008 on Windows 2008 R2 IIS?

Tags: wcf, iis, publish

I'm working on a WCF project with Visual Studio 2008 that needs to be regulary published on an external Windows 2008 R2 server. The project publishing is done for testing purposes, and needs to be done as easily as possible as it will happen often to refactor and republish it. What's the best, easiest and fastest way to publish it on the remote IIS?

Answer (score 0):

i use [CruiseControl.NET](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Welcome+to+CruiseControl.NET) for this purpose

Comment: It doesn't seems to be what I'm looking for.